# How can I block site visitors using legacy browsers

Tags: javascript, browsers, browser-support

I want my site to block access to visitors that are using outdated browsers such as *IE6* and *IE7* etc.

I am looking for a script that I can use to block certain browsers accessing my site

Comment: May I ask why do you want to block them?!

Comment: The only real reason for *not supporting* (different from "blocking") older browsers is that your web project not only makes use of, but *requires* the latest and most advanced browser to function. Is that your scenario? If so, what scripting environment are you using?

Comment: I'm blocking them because I can't be bothered supporting them. It might even be technically feasible to support even IE6 but as I'm a solo developer have to choose new features vs legacy browser support and chose the first. Only site access stats can tell me I'm wrong :)

Comment: Hmm... but don't do that! IMO start with a simple design which supports older browsers too, then expand it for new technologies. believe me, you'll loose a lot with blocking older browsers, there are many people who still use them, people who never upgrade their default IE... if youo're website is live atm, your stats should confirm this. even websites created solely for new browsers have some level of support for older ones...

Comment: "_better practices_" and "_blocking access to legacy browsers_" - isn't that a contradiction?!

Comment: @w3d No it's not in my view. This is a case where I'm aware of the trade-off but I still want to execute my vision in the best possible way given the circumstances.

Comment: @w3d sure, but not in the business world. OP is right in saying that only he can make the decision based on his perceived business needs. In the real world you don't always get to do best practices.

Comment: You are right. On several I've stopped supporting legacy browsers as soon as they became less than 5% of visitors and as a result improved the experience for everyone else which made the 95% grow! What I do not do is block them outright but the support form does not accept submissions from unsupported browsers in case they try to complain (with a message directing to supported a browser of course).

Comment: If you do decide to block rather than ignore them, I would do a server-side redirect instead of scripting since even a new browser can disable scripting.

Answer (score 3):

You can detect older versions of Internet Explorer using the [IE Conditional Comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) feature. The following snippet when included in a web page will redirect versions older than IE 8 to a separate page -

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="javascript">
location.href="legacy.html";
</SCRIPT>
<![endif]-->
```

You can also choose to hide the page's content by setting the container tag's display property style to none via JavaScript.

The browser can also be detected through server-side code.